# How I can do a double Reimann sum with one ecuation limit in python

Tags: python, numpy, math, compiler-errors, sympy

I'm triying to make a double reimann sum, with a limit b = (x^2 + y^2 = 16), the problem is when I use Sympy and marks as a TypeError in the linespace column, I tried to def the ecuation but nothing works, I'm doing somethin wrong or should I change something?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy

#  function to integrate = x +3*y + 1
# Limit funtion 'b' =(x^2 + y^2 = 16)
Width=15; Length=20;

x = sympy.Symbol('x')
a = 0
b =(sympy.sqrt(16-x**2))
c = 0
d = 3
#Heigth of x
deltax= (b - a) / Width
#Heigth of y
deltay = (d - c) / Length


#Area of each square
dA = deltax * deltay


x = np.linspace((a, b - deltax, Width));
y = np.linspace((c, d - deltay, Length));


f = lambda x,y: x +3*y + 1

[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(x, y);
#reimann sum
Suma=sum(dA * f(X, Y))
Suma = sum(Suma)

int(Suma)

print(Suma)
```

Comment: `numpy.linspace` take plain arguments not tuple. Something like `np.linspace(a, b - deltax, Ancho)`. Also numpy works with numbers but your `b - deltax` is symbolic object from sympy. This will not work.

Comment: Can I use another funtion apart from `numpy.linspace` ?